# FFMPEG losing quality when removing duplicate frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I currently use the command prompt to convert a video:

`ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -i "D:\clip.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB "D:\clip-converted.mp4"`

On the assumption of the principle of least surprise, I expected the saved video to be pretty much (or even EXACTLY) the same, apart from obviously with the duplicate frames removed. Although the duplicate frames were indeed removed, to my surprise, the video is much lower quality.

How can I resolve this? It should just take exactly the same encoded frames from the original, and put them into the new video. MP4/H.264 is modular like that, right? Or if it can't, then at least it should use the same quality as the input file? Right?

Failing being able to use the same quality frames as the original for the output, I would settle with a lossloss output, and/or saving each frame out individually to PNG/BMP. Preferably APNG (animated PNG) for the former and PNG for the latter.

For what it's worth, [this](https://skytopia.com/stuff/stun.mp4) is the video I'm trying to remove the duplicate frames from (without compromising quality).

Comment: Try with `-crf 0`. I also recommend to remove `-r 60`. `ffmpeg.exe -i stun.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 clip-converted.mp4`

Comment: Most frames in modern video codecs are interdependent. But that's not the issue here. It's just that you need to instruct *ffmpeg* on how to compress the output video. Otherwise some not so great defaults apply.

Comment: @Rotem - Thanks, I'm pretty sure I tried `-crf 0` before, but maybe without the zero, or maybe where it went nearer the beginning (where it fails to work). Didn't think the order was so important! Btw, didn't need the `-vcodec libx264` bit, and could keep the `-r 60` thankfully (I need it at 60fps).

Comment: @DanielB: I was hoping it would use the compression already present from the original video. Or at least recognize the compression type/quality used. Or maybe it has to redo/recompute the whole lot if you take out even just a single frame (or more) from within?

Comment: In H.264 streams there are **I** frames, **P** frames and **B** frames. Without re-encoding we can only cut the video in **I** frames which are also key frames. We can't just remove a random frame from the video stream. There may be some hack to remove frames without re-encoding, but it's complicated. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484854/4926757) for example.

Comment: @Twinbee ffmpeg won't figure out the encoding parameters in the input video to decide the encoding parameters for the output. It applies instead some built-in defaults, unless you explicitely give them in the command line.